# How do I get PC SAS to read a list from a text file and perform an action on each element in the list

Tags: sas

I have a PowerShell program that searches a folder on my PC for several text files.  If the file is not in the folder, it writes the filename to another text file.  When the procedure finishes, I have a text file with a list of files (one column) that are missing from the folder.

Next I would like PC SAS to read the list from the text file and launch the corresponding SAS program that I have already written that retrieves each file from our FTP server.

I am not sure how to go about having SAS read the filenames and launch my FTP programs.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: How does the current program learn what file it is to retrieve?  For example have you created a SAS macro that takes the filename as an input parameter?

Comment: The file names are hard coded in the SAS FTP program with the addition of a date tacked onto the end. . File1_20220718.txt, File2_20210719.txt...I want to replace this piece with a list of file names from the PowerShell script previously mentioned.  Basically, we have mainframe jobs that produce about 50 files each day.  Unfortunately, we struggle for MF processor time so the files are often delayed.  My PS program determines which files have not been downloaded and stores the list in a text file.  I want SAS to pick up the list and retrieve the files on a later run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the first problem is you need to modify the SAS program to use a dataset with the list of filenames to process.  One easy way to do that is to create a macro that downloads one file and takes the filename as an input parameter.  So convert your code that downloads a file to a macro.

```
%macro mf_download(file);
    * Code that downloads &FILE from mainframe. ;
%mend ;
```

Then it is easy to write a program that reads the names from a file and calls the macro for each name in the file.  So say the file with the list of names if named filelist.txt then that part of the program might look like this:

```
data names;
   infile 'filelist.txt' truncover ;
   input filename :$256. ;
   call execute(cats('%nrstr(%mf_download)(',filename,')'));
run;
```